# webdav and hardlinks Function not implemented error message

Tags: nginx, webdav, davfs2

I have webdav with nginx that I use to transfer files to a remote server. I mount it using davfs2 on a Debian box. The problem is that when I try to create a hardlink, I get the following error message:

```
ln: failed to create hard link 'cpool/test' => 'pc/test': Function not implemented
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without special extensions, WebDAV does not support creation of hard links.  The closest standard thing in WebDAV is a 'redirect reference resource' ([RFC 4437](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4437)), which results in returning a 3xx status code, and therefore behaves like a symbolic link, not a hard link.  The upstream http_dav module in nginx does not support this extension (and in fact, doesn't support some of the standard commands (`LOCK`, `UNLOCK`, `PROPFIND`, and `PROPPATCH` aren't supported by it).  I'm not sure if the third-party module does, but it wouldn't surprise me if it didn't seeing as outside of power users and sysadmins, most people don't user symlinks much either.